# Recognising last iteration in a Object loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have an Object like so:

```
var data = {
    "Something": true,
    "Something else": false,
    "Blah": false,
    "a fish": true
};
```

I then loop this Object, and add the key of any line that has true to a String

```
var stringContent = "";
for (var prop in data) {
    if (data[prop] === true) {
        stringContent += (prop) += ', ';
    }
}
```

So with the above, the String would be

```
Something, a fish
```

What I want to do however is recognise the last item added to the String.  For the very last iteration, I want to append the word And onto the front of the string.  So the above should end up being

```
Something, and a fish
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: "Added last" doesn't make a lot of sense when discussing object properties; they don't have a concept of order. You might want to consider a parallel structure that maintains order. Unless you just mean "last" is "whatever happens to be iterated over last", which seems pretty easy.

Comment: So an array instead?  Would this involve a lot of changes?

Comment: No clue, depends on how much stuff actually has to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does it. You need to get rid of the false elements first and then you can play around with what is left

```
let trues = Object.keys(data)
.filter(k => data[k])

return trues.slice(0,-1)
.join(',')
+ ', and ' + trues.slice(-1)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also can be done in this way.

```
        var inputstr = "Something, a fish";
        var values = inputstr.split(',');
        var last =" and " + values[values.length - 1];
        var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(',');
        str = str.substring(0, lastIndex);
        var finalstr= str + last;
```